# convert list of object to array

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, list

I am working where I need to create question randomly to use it later to create question paper, so what I have do is creating class Gene which represent question then create a list QuestionList of type gene then I create objects of gene through loop and store them in list QuestionList, now I need to convert the list to array s [] but I can't. Any one can help ?

here is my code , class and list which I defined in outer class

```
public class Gene
{
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string CLO { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Gene(string s, string t, string i)
    {
        this.question = s;
        this.type = t;
        this.CLO = i;
    }
  }
List<Gene> QuestionList = new List<Gene>();
```

then the loop to creating object which is located in function to make connection with sql

```
string s = "select * Question, CLO, Question_Type FROM QuestionBank WHERE (Subject = '" + sub + "') AND (chapter = '" + chapter + "') AND (Question_Type = '" + qt.name + "') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT = '" + qt.numOfType;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    con.Open();
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string ques = dr["Question"].ToString();
                        string questype = dr["Question_Type"].ToString();
                        string quesCLO = dr["CLO"].ToString(); 
                        QuestionList.Add(new Gene (ques, questype, quesCLO));
                    }
                     con.Close();
                   }
```

Now I need to convert the list to array

```
 string[] s = QestionList.ToArray();
```

I also try

```
 Gene[] s = QestionList.ToArray();
```

but none of them work, it show me error message "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property" ?

Comment: Where you are trying `Gene[] s = QestionList.ToArray();`? You cannot use one field to initialize another

Comment: yes, I fixed that but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @TimSchmelter in the outer class, main class

Comment: where in the outer/main class? As mentioned, if that's a field you cannot initialize it from another field. You _could_ do: `Gene[] s => QestionList.ToArray()`. But that would always create a new array when you access this property. It's called "Expression-bodied property"

Comment: Unrelated, but that SQL is **horribly** dangerous. Please please please use parameters. A tool like "Dapper" would make this entire thing trivial *and* allow parameters, for example: `Gene[] arr = con.Query<Gene>("select ... where foo = @subject and bar = @chapter ...", new { subject, chapter }).ToArray();`

Comment: @mjwills yes this work with me, thank you

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, it will help me a lot.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, thanks again

Comment: @Marc have it been discussed whether we should have a "Closed because of sql injection" close reason? I fear we are "teaching" people to let things like this slide by actually answering the questions as they stand and thus letting them "getting on with other things" without fixing this. As an industry, do we have responsibility for this? Not the right place to take this discussion though, just a thought on my end.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen well, *almost always* the error gets pointed out and advice offered; so ... an argument could be made that we ("the industry") are meeting our obligation there - perhaps more than meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or
>   property

The issue is that you have a field initializer referencing a non-static field, method or property. The C# compiler won't [allow that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236).

One solution is to move from a `field` to a `property`:

```
Gene[] s { get { return QestionList.ToArray(); } }
```

*The downside of above is that whenever you access `s` you are effectively cloning `QestionList` (i.e. it is expensive).*

Another would be to leave your field there:

```
Gene[] s;
```

and populate it inside your constructor instead:

```
s = QestionList.ToArray();
```

*The upside of doing it in the constructor is that the cloning will occur only once. That is also the downside (if you are altering `QestionList` then `s` won't reflect that).*

Comment: This is IMO a bad idea; properties should be cheap and repeatable (returning the same value); `ToArray()` is neither cheap nor repeatable.

Comment: That is a fair point @MarcGravell . Updated to reflect that. _I am not suggesting this is a good general practice, just trying to present code that the OP is likely to understand._

Answer (score 0):

This should work :). I think that you are using it in wrong place. Please show a code where are you converting list to array.

```
string s = "select * Question, CLO, Question_Type FROM QuestionBank WHERE (Subject = '" + sub + "') AND (chapter = '" + chapter + "') AND (Question_Type = '" + qt.name + "') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT = '" + qt.numOfType;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
                SqlDataReader dr;
                con.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string ques = dr["Question"].ToString();
                    string questype = dr["Question_Type"].ToString();
                    string quesCLO = dr["CLO"].ToString(); 
                    QuestionList.Add(new Gene (ques, questype, quesCLO));
                }
                 con.Close();
                 var geneArray = QuestionList.ToArray()
               }
```

Comment: But I don't need to initialize the array in the function because I need to use them in another class, but Thanks I find the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lists can trivially be converted to arrays via `ToArray()`. The real problem here is simply: timing and location. The code that calls `ToArray()` is fine in a method, for example it would be fine at the bottom of a method like:

```
Gene[] GetThings(string subject, string chapter, ...)
{
   var list = new List<Gene>();
   ... some code that populates list

   return list.ToArray();
}
```

Likewise, at the end of that method you could assign to a property or field:

```
   SomeMember = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: But I don't need to initialize the array in the function because I need to use them in another class, but Thanks I find the Solution.